# arithmetic on pandas dataframe row-wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

df have:

```
    A   B  C
a   1   2  3
b   2   1  4
c   1   1  1
```

df want:

```
    A   B  C
a   1   2  3
b   2   1  4
c   1   1  1
d   1  -1  1
```

I am able to get df want by using:

```
df.loc['d']=df.loc['b']-df.loc['a']
```

However, my actual df has 'a','b','c' rows for multiple IDs 'X', 'Y' etc.

```
        A   B  C
  X a   1   2  3
    b   2   1  4
    c   1   1  1
  Y a   1   2  3
    b   2   1  4
    c   1   1  1
```

How can I create the same output with multiple IDs? 
My original method:

```
df.loc['d']=df.loc['b']-df.loc['a']
```

fails KeyError:'b'

Desired output:

```
        A   B  C
  X a   1   2  3
    b   2   1  4
    c   1   1  1
    d   1  -1  1
  Y a   1   2  3
    b   2   2  4
    c   1   1  1
    d   1   0  1
```

Comment: It's a multi-index. You need to provide both the higher level and the lower level of the index to resolve the row

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
for i, sub in df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values(0)):
  df.loc[(i, 'd'), :] = sub.loc[(i,'b')] - sub.loc[(i, 'a')]

print(df.sort_index())
```

Or maybe

```
k = df.groupby(df.index.get_level_values(0), as_index=False).apply(lambda s: pd.DataFrame([s.loc[(s.name,'b')].values - s.loc[(s.name, 'a')].values], 
                                                                                      columns=s.columns, 
                                                                                      index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[s.name], ['d']], codes=[[0],[0]])
                                                                                      )).reset_index(drop=True, level=0)

pd.concat([k, df]).sort_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Data reshaping is a useful trick if you want to do manipulation on a particular level of a multiindex. See code below,

```
result = (df.unstack(0).T
            .assign(d=lambda x:x.b-x.a)
            .stack()
            .unstack(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.IndexSlice` to slice `a` and `b`.  Call `diff` and `slice` on `b` and `rename` it to `d`. Finally, append it to original `df`

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[idx[:,['a','b']],:].diff().loc[idx[:,'b'],:].rename({'b': 'd'})
df2 = df.append(df1).sort_index().astype(int)

Out[106]:
     A  B  C
X a  1  2  3
  b  2  1  4
  c  1  1  1
  d  1 -1  1
Y a  1  2  3
  b  2  2  4
  c  1  1  1
  d  1  0  1
```